# image and graphics format

Tags: image, png

what is the best format to save image and graphics so that it is visually consistant
in multiple browsers? i have been using png's and they look great in google chrome, but
not so good in other browsers. thanks

Comment: PNG is perfect for this purpose, you could tell us more on why you think it looks "not so good"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which graphic file formats are supported by browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183831/which-graphic-file-formats-are-supported-by-browsers)

Comment: By "other browsers", do you mean IE 6? Time to retire the poor old thing. Use PNGs for everything but photos.

Answer (score 0):

You should save...

- Photos in JPEG.
- Images that are not photos (large slabs of one colour, etc), transparencies as PNG.
- GIF for anything animated (can be emulated with JavaScript). ANG is not widely supported yet.