# What is the complete list of valid file extensions for images?

Tags: php, image, file-upload, file-extension

And the images I'm referring to are the ones that can be embeddable in a web browser not .tif, .psd, etc.

So the only ones I'm aware of are .png / .jpg / .jpeg / .gif / .bmp

are there any more?

Reason why I need this info is to only allow valid images to be uploaded in my php file upload script.

Comment: duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183831/which-graphic-file-formats-are-supported-by-browsers

Comment: And you expect to be able to do this just by looking at the file extension?

Comment: Define "a web browser", `bmp` support is far from universal.

Comment: To expand on Ignacio's comment — Do you really trust everybody who might try to upload a file to not be disguising something else with a false file extension and/or mime type?

Comment: @Ignacio actually I will be checking the $_FILE[type] returned by PHP, I wrote a small script that shows the type of any file, so to get the needed types I need some test files with the proper extensions.

Answer (score 4):

you can do what ever you like, its all about the headers, and the information inside the actual image that determines the type. (mime-types)

hence why `<img href='http://site.com/image.php?name=file'>` could actually render an image

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a direct answer to this question, but since you mentioned that the purpose of this is to restrict a file upload, the HTML5 answer to this problem would be to use:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

In addition to that you may also want a server-side check.

In terms of all possible valid image types, there isn't really a simple answer, but most of the information you would need to construct one would be to consult with [this list on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats). It of course depends a bit on what the image is going to be used for. The set of images that can be rendered by a browser is going to be different from the set that can be opened in photoshop.