# What types of image can I display using <img>? (2013)

Tags: html, image, cross-browser, image-formats

What are the different types of images that can be displayed using the `<img>` tag in HMTL?

Comment: Already answered here [Which graphic file formats are supported by browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183831/which-graphic-file-formats-are-supported-by-browsers)

Comment: @saamorim: that was 5 years ago; a lot can change in 5 years (even if it doesn't really change what you can reasonably use)

Comment: @SamB, the answer redirects the user to a wikipedia website which was, at the current time, last updated on 11/Jan/2014. So imo the answer is still valid.

Comment: @saamorim: well, you know the rules about link-only answers ...

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers supports the most common subtypes of GIF, JPEG and PNG.