# What kind of image could be in the source of <img> tag?

Tags: html

Sample:

```
 <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

What kind of images could I use as resources (gif, .... ?) Are there any limitations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which graphic file formats are supported by browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183831/which-graphic-file-formats-are-supported-by-browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img):

> The HTML standard doesn't give a list of image formats that must be
>   supported, so each user agent supports a different set of formats.
>   Gecko supports:
>
> JPEG 
>   GIF, including animated GIFs 
>   PNG 
>   APNG 
>   SVG 
>   BMP 
>   BMP ICO 
>   PNG ICO

The [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) and [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-img-src) go on to say:

> ...images can be static bitmaps (e.g. PNGs, GIFs, JPEGs), single-page
>   vector documents (single-page PDFs, XML files with an SVG root
>   element), animated bitmaps (APNGs, animated GIFs), animated vector
>   graphics (XML files with an SVG root element that use declarative SMIL
>   animation), and so forth. However, these definitions preclude SVG
>   files with script, multipage PDF files, interactive MNG files, HTML
>   documents, plain text documents, and so forth.