# Is it possible to display .bin image files on a web page without converting it to jpg/png/gif?

Tags: php, html, apache, imagemagick

I am able to view the `.bin` image files using display command in ImageMagick.

```
display -size 512x512 -depth 32 -equalize gray:<filename>
```

I was able to convert it to jpg format and then display on a webpage.
But I need to display the file without converting it to jpg.

Using php `exec()`, it was possible to display the file when running the php file on terminal but not on apache web server.
Is there a way to display the `.bin` image file on a web page?
Please help me as I have been trying this for many days...

Comment: What is a `.bin` image? Usually, `.bin` is used for CD image like `.iso`? Is this a graphical file like `.png`?

Comment: yes it is a graphical file.It is possible to convert it to jpg/png etc formats

Comment: I have never heard of graphical `.bin` images. And so does the "Image Format Support" chart on Wikipedia. You should only use image formats for web development, which are widely supported. This means, a conversion of your images would be most preferable. http://stackoverflow.com/q/183831/3233827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

The `gray:` protocol will only output an image data blob. There is no image headers, and various important meta-data (like size, depth, & etc) are not communicated/transported.

Even `display` requires you to, at minimum, specify size + depth before it can read the `.bin` file.

However, if you *can* communicate the depth & width to the web browser, you can *rebuild* the image with Javascript & `<canvas>` tag. But that would be labor intensive, and the load-time results would be unpleasant for end-users.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Is it possible to call a script that executes the display command from a web page?

Comment: Also no. Well. If the bin resource _is_ served from the HTTP service, then you can show people the `display` commands to view remote resources. Or even write an application & [register a URL schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx), but that's a lot of work.

Comment: Is it feasible/worth to write a browser plugin/java applet (or something else) to be able to display the .bin file on a web browser? (The .bin file contains raw image data)

Comment: Feasible, yes. Worth it, no. Honestly, just create a "web-only preview" for browser display. Modern image formats (png/webp) are very good at compression / fault tolerance. If you attempt a plugin you may discover that the raw data will be [clamped to 8-bit color depth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData).